# Magento-2 : How to move breadcrumbs and maincontent in custom div on category page

Tags: magento2, layout

I need to create one custom div and move below div inside custom div

Category page html structure like this

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">...</div>
<main id="maincontent" class="page-main">...</main>
```

I need to something like this

```
<div class="mycustom-div">
    <div class="breadcrumbs">...</div>
    <main id="maincontent" class="page-main">...</main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have done by add below code to

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/MyTheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="page.top">
    <container name="mycustom.div" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="mycustom-div" />
</referenceContainer>
<move element="breadcrumbs" destination="mycustom.div" before="main.content"/>
<move element="main.content" destination="mycustom.div" after="breadcrumbs"/>
```

Comment: how to move breadcrumb to left nav

Answer (score 4):

#### I want to put this here for future Magento 2 adventurers.

I created a new **page_layout** for my product but had the hardest time figuring out how to add breadcrumbs to my custom page_layout. Here is how I did it with @suresh Chikani's help.
`magento2/app/design/frontend/<DesignName>/<SubDesign>/Magento_Theme/page_layout/custom-page.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>

    <move element="breadcrumbs" destination="page.wrapper" before="main.content"/>

    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper" >
        <referenceContainer name="main.content">
            <referenceContainer name="columns">
                <referenceContainer name="main">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom-page" as="custom-page" template="Magento_Theme::custom-page.phtml" before="-"/>
                </referenceContainer>
            </referenceContainer>
        </referenceContainer>

        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I know it's not an answer to the question but I made it here looking for this and your answer helped. I hope it can help others (or me) in the future.